# ActionMailer repeat body in mail with attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, attachment, actionmailer

I'm trying to send a email with a attachment. The email is received, but the body of the message appears three times.

This is my code:

```
class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def bill_assignments(user, bill)
    @receiver = user
    @bill = bill
    path = Rails.root.join('tmp', "#{@bill.reference}.pdf")
    attachments["#{@bill.reference}.pdf"] = File.read(path)
    mail(to: user.email, bcc: 'contact@domain.com', subject: "Bill")
    # Elimina el archivo si existe
    File.delete(path) if File.exist?(path)
  end
end
```

Also I overrided the mail method to sure that the receiver is enabled:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  attr_reader :receiver
  def mail(*arg, &block)
    if @receiver.deleted_at.nil?
      super
    end
  end
end
```

I know that the problem is the overrided method mail. If I quit this method the code works fine, but I need it to sure if the receiver user is enabled.

Only occurs whit attachments. If is only plain text the body is printed only one time, but if I have attachament the body is printed three times.

I don't know why fail. I think that my method is ok. If the condition is true I call the super.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share views files of this mailer ?

Comment: And your actual code can't work (Syntax error) double closing parentheses`mail(..., subject: "Bill"))`

Comment: Sorry. I make a mistake when copied the code.

Also I have observed that the fail is when I override the method mail in ApplicationMailer. 

If I quit the overrided method the code works fine.

Any suggestions about why?

Comment: If it's caused by override try to move your condition `@receiver.deleted_at.nil?` elsewhere, for example directly in
    `def bill_assignments(user, bill);
       return if (@receiver = user).deleted_at.nil?;
       ...
    end`

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But I want to know, why I can't override the method. I thought that I was doing correctly. In fact with others methods this way is correct.